# Load a UITabBarController From UIViewController button Click

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How to load a UITabBarController From UIViewController button Click?

I had Attached my StoryBoard Design [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/anikvsd78ccu7ea/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-04%20at%2010.11.43%20am.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control-drag from your button to the tab bar view controller. Select modal presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an action on UIButton and either Push or Modally present the TabBarViewController.
To doing so press Ctrl + Click on button and drag mouse pointer to your TabBarController, StoryBoard will popup the action type, Select one from them.